# Can't bind/send data between two sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, packet

I am trying to send packet data between two sockets using socket programming in python, basically the instructions Ive been given is to make 6 routers (im just doing two right now) and have them send packets to eachother and such, the instructions specify that I have to run the second router first then run the first (the first is the one that is reading the packets.csv file) But whenever I run the second router and then the first I get this error form the first

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "router1_skeleton.py", line 185, in <module>
    socket = create_socket(host,port)
  File "router1_skeleton.py", line 15, in create_socket
    soc.bind((host,port))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

If I understand correctly the way to make this work is to set up the socket in router 2 which I have here

```
  # 1. Create a socket.
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # 2. Try connecting the socket to the host and port.
    soc.bind((host,port))
    soc.listen(5)
    try:
        conn,addr = soc.accept()
    except:
        print("Connection Error to", port)
        sys.exit()
    # 3. Return the connected socket.
    return soc
```

And then for my first router I write

```
def create_socket(host, port):
    # 1. Create a socket.
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # 2. Try connecting the socket to the host and port.
    soc.bind((host,port))
    soc.listen(5)
    try:
        #print("hello")
        conn,addr = soc.accept()
        print("Received connection fron:", addr)
        conn.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())
    except:
        print("Connection Error to", port)
        sys.exit()
    # 3. Return the connected socket.
    #print(soc)
    return soc
```

Then I send data using soc.send(new_packet.encode())

and router 2 should be getting the data with this line and it should be working but it breaks along here

```
while True:
        # 8. Accept the connection.
        connection, address = soc.accept()
        print("Accepted a connection from: ", address)
        data = soc.rev(1024)
        print(data.decode())
        ##ip, port = 
        print("Connected with " + ip + ":" + port)
```

Any suggestions are very welcome!

EDIT: Broken pipe / Transport endpoint error

```
if newport == 2:
    print("sending packet", new_packet, "to Router 2")
    socket.send(new_packet.encode())
    write_to_file("output/sent_by_router_1.txt", new_packet, 2)
```

I use this to send the data to router 2 and this should receive it

```
 while True:
        # 8. Accept the connection.
        connection, address = soc.accept()
        print("Accepted a connection from: ", address)
        data = soc.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode())
```

This is the error I get

```
 File "router1_skeleton.py", line 237, in <module>
    socket.send(new_packet.encode())
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: You cannot have two processes binding to the same port, simultaneously. Use a different port for each process (both acting as server). Or bind in one process (acting as server) and connect on the same port in the second process (acting as client).

Comment: When you have them use diffrent ports is there a certain way to send the data? I use socket.send(new_packet.encode()) and have a data.decode() in my second process but I just get a broken pipe error

Comment: You need to post the relevant code. There is no code calling `connect()` to connect to a server process.

Comment: I added the sending/receiving code for the data please let me know what else you need to see!

Comment: You cannot send and receiving using the socket (`soc`) that you bind. You have to use the socket that is the result of the `accept()` call (`conn`) to send and receive data.